# Window size issue with jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website, each div is calculated on the window size...

```
// Begin functions 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper').css({'top' : '0px','left' : '0px'});
        $('.wrapper > div').css({'height' : + $(window).height() +'px'});
});


$(document).ready(init);

// Set window height and width variables 
var windowheight = $(window).height(); 
var windowwidth = $(window).width(); 

// Check monitor sze and workot if incentives needs extra space etc 
var bff = 3620 + (1993 - windowwidth);

// Move divs into position 
$('.culture').css('top', + - windowheight + 'px');
$('.path').css('top', + - windowheight + 'px');
$('.training').css('top', + - windowheight + 'px');
$('.apply').css({
    'top' : + - windowheight + 'px',
    'width' : windowwidth + 'px'
});
```

The above works fine, my problem is, that when the page has loaded, if the user then resizes there window, the styling is thrown off as the divs have already been loaded, is there a way with jquery to detect this and then reinitialise the above?

Comment: Simple solution: don't use javascript for UI concerns. This can be done in CSS alone by ensuring `height: 100%` is set the required element and all parents.

Comment: The website uses the jQuery scrollpath plugin and isnt as straightforward as that @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Where is your `init()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find if window has been resized using `$(window).resize()` in jQuery.
http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to resize events width jquery, this way every time a window is resized you can call your code to set things in place.

The next line will call your initialization function:

```
$(window).resize(init);
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying @EduardoFerrónn It doesn't seem to work however, the funcrion doesnt re-run

Comment: Could it be that jQuery can't find your function? Or maybe those lines where you take the actual size of the window are out of that "init" function so they don't get updated?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `$(window).on('resize', init)`?

Answer (score 0):

Using the window onresize would work.

However, if possible, I would use plain CSS to achieve this, something like:

HTML

```
<div id="main-container">
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

This way, the browser will handle that for you, saving calculation trouble.

The key here are the bottom and right styles, which only work when position=absolute or position=fixed.